# SQL Server : Incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server

I have problem with this T-SQL code:

```
SELECT 
  DQ.Code as DQ_Code, II.OrdNumber AS Cislo, II.Id As ID,
  convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DocDate$DATE as datetime), 104) as DatumPlneni,
  convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) as DatumSplatnosti,
  F.Name as Firma, F.ID as FIRMID,
(II.LocalAmount - II.LocalCreditAmount) as LocalAmount,
(II.LocalPaidAmount) as LocalPaidAmount,
(II.LocalAmount - II.LocalCreditAmount - II.LocalPaidAmount + II.LocalPaidCreditAmount) as LocalNotPaidAmount,
 case
   when 
    ((case 
        when len(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) )=10 
          then convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104)
        when ((len(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) )=9) and (substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 7 for 1) ='-'))
          then substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 1 for 5)||'0'||substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 6 for 10)  
        when ((len(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) )=9) and (substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 7 for 1)<>'-'))  
          then substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 1 for 8)||'0'||substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 9 for 10)  
        when len(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) )=8 
          then substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 1 for 5)||'0'||substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 6 for 2) ||'0'||substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 8 for 2) 
      end) < cast(current_date as varchar(10)) 
     )
    then II.LocalAmount - II.LocalCreditAmount - II.LocalPaidAmount + II.LocalPaidCreditAmount
   when 
    ((case 
        when len(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) )=10 
          then convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104)
        when ((len(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) )=9) and (substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 7 for 1) ='-'))
          then substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 1 for 5)||'0'||substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 6 for 10)  
        when ((len(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) )=9) and (substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 7 for 1)<>'-'))  
          then substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 1 for 8)||'0'||substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 9 for 10)  
        when len(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) )=8 
          then substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 1 for 5)||'0'||substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 6 for 2) ||'0'||substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 8 for 2) 
      end) > cast(current_date as varchar(10)) 
     )
    then 0
    end as NotPaidAfterDueD
FROM 
  IssuedInvoices II
LEFT JOIN DocQueues DQ ON DQ.ID=II.Docqueue_ID
LEFT JOIN Firms F ON F.ID=II.Firm_ID
WHERE 
  (II.LocalAmount - II.LocalCreditAmount - II.LocalPaidAmount + II.LocalPaidCreditAmount)>0
```

When I try run it in DBeaver I get this error:

> *SQL Error [156] [S1000]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.*

My problem is most likely in CASE part, but I can't resolve where exactly. Can you someone help me please?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: If you tried a [sql formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm), it would tell you where the problem is. (Line 14, Col 162)

Answer (score 11):

You have a few problems.

First, is in your `CASE` statements, you are using syntax for `substring` similar to this:

```
substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.DueDate$DATE as datetime), 104) from 7 for 1) ='-')
```

The [`substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) syntax is:

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
```

You will notice that there is no `from` used.  So your code would be something like:

```
substring(convert(varchar(10), cast(II.[DueDate$DATE] as datetime), 104), 7, 1) ='-'
```

Second, you are using pipes `||` to concatenate data together in SQL Server you will want to use a plus sign `+`. So replace:

```
...5)||'0'||substring...
```

With:

```
...5)+'0'+substring...
```

Third, replace the `current_date` with `getdate()`. Another thing you will have to fix when you replace the `current_date` with `getdate()` is the following:

```
cast(getdate() as varchar(10))
```

This will return a value of the current date in a format that you will not want to use.  I recommend looking at the following website to determine the best format for your comparison:

[How to format datetime & date in Sql Server 2005](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Typically, you would want to use something like:

```
convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112) – yyyymmdd
```

Last, any columns that have a special character in them `DueDate$DATE` need to be wrapped in square brackets. So they will look like:

```
...cast(II.[DueDate$DATE]...
```

Comment: @Sk1X1 I saw your comment that you posted as an answer. You need to use the square brackets because your column names have special characters in them.

Comment: @Sk1X1 Welcome to StackOverflow! If this answer or any answer to your questions is helpful, then consider accepting it via the checkmark to the left of it. See [How does accepting answers work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).